# How to dynamically change icons in flutter gridtile cards once triggered on tap

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

Im pretty new to fultter and im trying to make a grid that has tappable cards. I want to choose what to plant and have the icon change as well the information from that plant to saved to that individual gridtile. I was wondering how do you set a new state for a specific gridtile once it is triggered? I attached the code below. I cant seem to get the icon on the gridtile to change from the shovel icon to the sprout icon using the stateful widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_flutter_app_icons.dart';


class WindowSillGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WindowSillGridState createState() => _WindowSillGridState();
}

class _WindowSillGridState extends State<WindowSillGrid> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = "Window Sill Grid";

    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
            appBar: AppBar(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
     bottom: Radius.circular(20))),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
              title: Text(title),
            ),
        body: GridView.count(
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: List.generate(6, (index) {
              return Center(
                child: ChoiceCard(choice: PlantGrowth[index]),
                  );
                }))));
 }
}

class PlantGrowthIcons {
  const PlantGrowthIcons({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
 }

const List<PlantGrowthIcons> PlantGrowth = const <PlantGrowthIcons>[
  const PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MyFlutterApp.shovel),
  const PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MyFlutterApp.shovel),
  const PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MyFlutterApp.shovel),
  const PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MyFlutterApp.shovel),
  const PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MyFlutterApp.shovel),
  const PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MyFlutterApp.shovel),


];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final PlantGrowthIcons choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () { 
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WindowSillGridEditPage()));},
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.brown[300],
         child: GridTile(
          child: Card(
          color: Colors.brown[400],
         child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(choice.icon, size: 80.0, color: Colors.white),
                  Text(choice.title,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                 ],
             ),
          ),
          ),
    ),
    ),
    );
   }
}

 const List<Widget> items = const[
      ListTile(
       leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.sprout, size: 50),
        title: Text('Asparagus'),
        subtitle: Text('Description here'),
        ),
      ListTile(
         leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.sprout, size: 50),
         title: Text('Egg Plant'),
         subtitle: Text('Description here')
       ),
      ListTile(
         leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.sprout, size: 50),
         title: Text('Tomato'),
         subtitle: Text('Description here'),
       ),
       ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.sprout, size: 50),
        title: Text('Cucumber'),
        subtitle: Text('Description here'),
       ),
  

class WindowSillGridEditPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         centerTitle: true,
         backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
         title: Text('Plant3r'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child:
    ListView(

      itemExtent: 60,
      children: items,
    ),

  ),
);}
}
```

Comment: Icons can be variables. assign an icon to an icon variable and use that variable for your leading. Eg. Icon myIcon=Icon(MyFlutterApp.sprout, size: 50); then place this on leading: myIcon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can in `ChoiceCard` pass `index` and `refresh` callback 
And set `PlantGrowth[widget.index].icon = MdiIcons.sprout;` with `InkWell`

code snippet

```
ChoiceCard(
                        choice: PlantGrowth[index],
                        index: index,
                        callback: refresh),
...                     
return InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
        await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => WindowSillGridEditPage(index: index)));
        callback();
...     
@override
  initState() {
    items = [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].title = "Asparagus";
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].icon = MdiIcons.sprout;
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MdiIcons.sprout, size: 50),
          title: Text('Asparagus'),
          subtitle: Text('Description here'),
        ),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';

class WindowSillGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WindowSillGridState createState() => _WindowSillGridState();
}

class _WindowSillGridState extends State<WindowSillGrid> {
  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = "Window Sill Grid";

    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
            appBar: AppBar(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20))),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
              title: Text(title),
            ),
            body: GridView.count(
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: List.generate(6, (index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ChoiceCard(
                        choice: PlantGrowth[index],
                        index: index,
                        callback: refresh),
                  );
                }))));
  }
}

class PlantGrowthIcons {
  PlantGrowthIcons({this.title, this.icon});

  String title;
  IconData icon;
}

List<PlantGrowthIcons> PlantGrowth = <PlantGrowthIcons>[
  PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MdiIcons.shovel),
  PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MdiIcons.shovel),
  PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MdiIcons.shovel),
  PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MdiIcons.shovel),
  PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MdiIcons.shovel),
  PlantGrowthIcons(title: 'Add Plant', icon: MdiIcons.shovel),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice, this.index, this.callback})
      : super(key: key);
  PlantGrowthIcons choice;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
        await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => WindowSillGridEditPage(index: index)));
        callback();
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.brown[300],
        child: GridTile(
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.brown[400],
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(choice.icon, size: 80.0, color: Colors.white),
                  Text(
                    choice.title,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WindowSillGridEditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  WindowSillGridEditPage({this.index});

  @override
  _WindowSillGridEditPageState createState() => _WindowSillGridEditPageState();
}

class _WindowSillGridEditPageState extends State<WindowSillGridEditPage> {
  List<Widget> items;

  @override
  initState() {
    items = [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].title = "Asparagus";
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].icon = MdiIcons.sprout;
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MdiIcons.sprout, size: 50),
          title: Text('Asparagus'),
          subtitle: Text('Description here'),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].title = "Egg Plant";
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].icon = MdiIcons.sprout;
        },
        child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(MdiIcons.sprout, size: 50),
            title: Text('Egg Plant'),
            subtitle: Text('Description here')),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].title = "Tomato";
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].icon = MdiIcons.sprout;
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MdiIcons.sprout, size: 50),
          title: Text('Tomato'),
          subtitle: Text('Description here'),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].title = "Cucumber";
          PlantGrowth[widget.index].icon = MdiIcons.sprout;
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MdiIcons.sprout, size: 50),
          title: Text('Cucumber'),
          subtitle: Text('Description here'),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
        title: Text('Plant3r'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          itemExtent: 60,
          children: items,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: WindowSillGrid(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: grate work :) 
I have a similar question is it possible to make subtitle dynamic?